# ORA-02065: illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM

Tags: oracle, database-backups, oracle-enterprise-manager

I'm new to Oracle. I was learning Backup and Recovery. For that, I did

> $ sqlplus system/password
>
> SQL> alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size=8gb scope=both;

But I got error this error:-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ3qD.png)

Can anyone tell me the exact solution? Please do tell me the specific solution with all the steps to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sqlplus system/password
```

SQL> alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size=**8g** scope=both;